# how to make HTTPRequest with json in swift

Tags: json, swift

I am making an ios application. I am new to swift and not able to understand my code. can anyone please help me to understand what is going on with my code.

This is login application on adding email id if the email exist it should go to next view controller and if not then it should give error. I am getting difficulty in understanding my code .

Here is my code:

```
class checkLoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkUsernametextfield: UITextField!

    @IBAction func checkUsernameButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Clicked On SUbmit !!!!")

        //Read Value from Text
        let email = checkUsernametextfield.text
let myUrl = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.117/rest/signup.php");

        var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

        let postString = "email=\(String(describing: email))";

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

            //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                    let emailValue = parseJSON["email"] as? String
                    print("email: \(String(describing: emailValue))")
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

Output:

> Clicked On SUbmit !!!! response = Optional( { URL: http://192.168.0.117/rest/signup.php } { Status
>   Code: 200, Headers {
>       Connection =     (
>           "Keep-Alive"
>       );
>       "Content-Length" =     (
>           61
>       );
>       "Content-Type" =     (
>           "application/json"
>       );
>       Date =     (
>           "Mon, 12 Mar 2018 06:35:58 GMT"
>       );
>       "Keep-Alive" =     (
>           "timeout=5, max=100"
>       );
>       Server =     (
>           "Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu)"
>       ); } }) email: nil

Comment: Request seems correct (you got a 200), but could you print `let jsonStr = String(data, encoding:.utf8)` and give us its value? Issue seems to be with JSON (your response has after all a 61 length message and a 200).

Comment: the request to php is going blank . the value which i input in textfield does not show in php log

Comment: i did not understand ??? @Larme

Comment: Coule you print jsonStr?

Comment: i will try to do that @Larme

Comment: thank you @Larme for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this. Hope it works.

```
  let url = URL(string:"http://192.168.0.117/rest/signup.php")
        let parameters = ["email": checkUsernametextfield.text]
        var request = URLRequest(url : url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options: [])
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
          if let data = data {
                do {
                    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Dictionary<String, Any>
                    if let json = json {
                        print("HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON \(json)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
            }
        }).resume()
```

Comment: yes it worked .. but how did u do that . like could you please explain it . i am at beginner level sorry for asking this type of question

Comment: I think the issue was with the wrong email format. I usually use Json format [String:Any].  And that's what I did, instead of         let postString = "email=\(String(describing: email))"; I used         let parameters = ["email": checkUsernametextfield.text] . I set it to the request body as JSON         request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options: [])
and specified it  type       request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") . 
 I usually use this approach.

Comment: thank you so much @Captain Alina .. now i just have to figure out the way to do if the response is 200 then need to go to next view controller if not then to be in the same

Comment: if let json = json { print("HERE SHOULD BE YOUR JSON \(json)") } Here how can i extract data from "json" i am getting values as status , id , name , dept ... i want to print status and use it ?? how can i acheive that

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: https://medium.com/tsengineering/swift-4-0-codable-decoding-subclasses-inherited-classes-heterogeneous-arrays-ee3e180eb556

Comment: I have got the status using dictionary . now i am trying using the way u say . its very simple using protocols . thank you so much for your time . Happy coding @Captain Alina

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to send request.

```
enter code here

static func downloadConfig(url:URL, completion:@escaping (_ sucess:Bool , _ jsonObject: [String: String]?)->() ) {

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,response,error) in

        if let data = data ,let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200 {

                do {
                if let todoJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: String]{
                    completion(true,todoJSON)
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(false,nil)
                }
            }
            catch {
                //erro parsing
                completion(false,nil)
            }

        }
        else
        {
            completion(false,nil)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

use this download json function in this way.

```
//Download Json File
    let base_url = "base_url"
    let urlstr = String.init(format: "%@", base_url)
    let url = URL(string: urlstr)

    GameUtil.downloadConfig(url: url!) {
        (sucess: Bool , jsonObject: [String:String]?) in

        if sucess , jsonObject != nil
        {
            self.configJson = jsonObject!

        }

    }
```

Comment: you are making GET request, however author posted question about POST request.

Comment: User got "Status Code: 200", so I'd tend to say that the issue is about the parsing, not the method until we get the full response, we can only speculate.